# console based application using box.com outh with out asking user to login and allow the app

Tags: box-api

Here is my situation. I am developing a console based application using c#. Here we can not have user login. Only i can do is using api i need to get auth_code then access token and refresh token. I am very happy if somebody can answer, how to implement this in my console app. i mean how to get the auth_code with out asking user to login and allow the application.

Here if i run a cURL command i am getting html response, which is the complete html for box login page.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

The current OAuth 2 flow requires the user to go through the browser and can't be done programmatically.